# React-native: Build failed CompileC (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, npx

Whilst trying to build a react-native app to run in ios sim the following error occurs:

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/nikospapadakos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MCRProfessionalApplication-fxqjlrbknzuqlxfpkgyuaqdhmvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JSIInstaller.o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MCR_Professional_Application/node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/JSI/JSIInstaller.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')

Please let me know of any additional info you need to help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well when I had created the expo project using "minimal" Bare workflow:

> export init

> minimal

> expo run:ios

but when I used the "blank" managed workflow, everything worked as expected.

I couldn't find anything useful on why the "minimal" was having an issue.

Comment: i ended up paying someone to fix it

Comment: Did they explain?